# Determine the transient response

Tags: control-theory

How do i Determine the transient response of an transfer function if it's in the s domain?? 
the obvious answer would be using inverse laplace transform, but how come??

consider i have system like this
$\frac{2+1}{s(s+1)^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Hints: You search for the partial fraction decomposition of the given expression as in writing it as  $A/s +B/(s+1) + C/(s+1)^2$, and find $A,B,C$. Then the inverse Laplace transform of $ K/(s+a)^n$ is $Ke^{-at}t^{n-1}/(n-1)!$. Then you add the contributions from each of the three terms.

Comment: ok... That's easy,but i am having i bit of a problem here. My system sould be stable or partially since my poles are located at s = 0, S = -1 and S = -1. but why isn't my step response of the system a bounded output???

I determine the step reponse by multiplying 1/s to the system while it is in the S - domain,and then use Partial fraction decomposition and Inverse laplace to which give this result $\frac{3}{s^2} - \frac{6}{s} + \frac{3}{(1+s)^2} + \frac{6}{1+s} => inverse laplace => -6 + 6 E^{-t} + 3t + 3 E^{-t}t$ which isn't a bounded output.

Comment: (1) When there is a step function then typically there is a $e^{-s}$ multiple in the expression in the $s$ domain. (2) The original expression has a $2+1$ in numerator, is that right or is it $2s+1$ or?

Comment: Indeed @Maesumi I think he made a typo and means $2s + 1$. In that case the impulse response is stable.

Comment: $\frac{3}{s(s+1)^2}$ is just a system. By multiplying 1/s i apply a step function to it, and by doing partial fraction decomposition and inverse laplace transformation, is the function i got the one i wrote before. 

The when i plot it, I should be able to see how it reponse to a step, and since my poles are placed on the left side it should be stable.  But how come is my plot unstable => unbounded output??